# Meta Description Content Not Showing In Google Search Result Page

Tags: php, html, seo, google-search

I think i am having some critical meta tag issue in my website. When i search my website in google, In the search result, Website title and name showing correct information but in place of description some other content is showing which is not the meta description content but some parts of the content of my website's home page. My website is developed in PHP-based opensource opencart.

i searched a lot to resolve it but still i got no solution. I have no previous experience in seo that makes me estimate something without sufficient information to be sure where the error is. If anyone helps me out here that would be really great. I attached an screenshot for better understanding.

[image: The screenshot of the google search result]

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, ensure that you are following the structure which is shown in https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en

This means that your tag should look like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="A description of the page" />
```

Something that could be causing this problem is that Google does not update descriptions automatically- so you may have to wait until they crawl your website again, for it to update (you could use the Google Webmaster systems to encourage this).

Answer (score -1):

> Google will sometimes use the meta description of a page in search
>   results snippets, if we think it gives users a more accurate
>   description than would be possible purely from the on-page content
>   https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?rd=1

google only sometimes uses your meta description. Other times, it uses page content.